# Using <div> tag for pdf printing

Tags: templates, pdf, html

I have made a html-template in CiviCRM consisting only of this kind of html tag:
<div style="position: absolute;">

This works perfect for selecting a template for pdf printing, when printing only one page. Then I have the opportunity to place certain elements at the appropriate place on my letter.

The problem arises, when selecting a bunch of contacts, and then creating pdf-s to all of them at the same time. Then it only prints all on one single pdf-page, instead of one page pr. contact. I want the CiviCRM-template to print the <div> tag on one page pr. contact.

Is there a trick here I don't know? And if so, please explain...

(My site is using wkhtmltopdf to generate the pdf-s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out on my own.
To print `<div>` on different pages, it needs to be positioned relative.

So, I ended up putting all the existing `<div>` with position absolute into a `<div>` with position relative.

However, that is not sufficient enough, I also needed to fill in a simple `<br />` tag as well.

This worked:

`<div id="page" style="position: relative;">`

`<br />`

`<div id="content" style="position: absolute;">`

`</div>`

`</div>`